# How to create auto generated id in JSP

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I have a jsp page in which employee can register himself and I want to create unique id for every employee now employee can enter id manually and I want it auto generated..... anyone please help me how I can do it?

my back-end database is MYSQL, ID column is set to auto increment but its not working employee can enter id manually

Comment: Don't expose an ID to the user and make sure that an ID field is not persisted when creating the record in the DB. The ID should be internal use only.

Comment: Because ID column is not incremented automatically that is my question

Comment: Execute `show create table table_name_here` and check if it shows whether `auto_increment` is defined or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL default settings, an auto_increment value will not be used for inserted rows, if you insert a NOT NULL value.

Given, your table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Either insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO
employees
( id, name )
VALUES
( NULL, 'Tom Smith' )
```

or don't set the id value at all

```
INSERT INTO
employees
( name )
VALUES
( 'Tom Smith' )
```

Have a look at this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html